# Arangodb - working with EDGE getting assertion error edge._key equal

Tags: node.js, arangodb

I am working with Arangodb and Node.js. I am trying use the edgecollection in the db. I have downloaded arangojs from npm and trying out the example codes.

```
// ## Assigning the values
const arangojs = require('arangojs');
const aqlQuery = arangojs.aqlQuery;
const now = Date.now();

 //  ## Const variables for connecting to ArangoDB database

 const host = '192.100.00.000'
 const port = '8529'
 const username = 'xyz' 
 const password = 'XYZ'
 const path = '/_db/sgcdm_app/_api/'
 const database = 'sgcdm_app'

// ## Connection to ArangoDB

db = new arangojs.Database({
url: http://${host}:${port},
databaseName: database
});
db.useBasicAuth(username, password);

// ## Working with EDGES

const collection = db.edgeCollection('included_in');
const edge = collection.edge('included_in/595783');
const assert = require('assert');

// the edge exists

assert.equal(edge._key, '595783');
assert.equal(edge._id, 'included_in/595783');
console.log(db);
```

**ERROR:**

> ```
> assert.js:42
> throw new errors.AssertionError({
> AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: undefined == '595783'
> ```

Comment: What makes you think the undefined edge is actually in the `included_in` collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented, `edgeCollection.edge()` is **asynchronous**: https://github.com/arangodb/arangojs#edgecollectionedge

It returns a **Promise**, not an edge:

```
collection.edge('included_in/595783');

Promise {
  <pending>,
  domain:
   Domain {
     domain: null,
     _events: { error: [Function: debugDomainError] },
     _eventsCount: 1,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     members: [] } }
```

You have to `await` the result or use `then()` to do something with the result as soon as it becomes available.

```
collection.edge('included_in/595783')
.then(res => { console.log("Key: " + res._key } ));

Key: 595783
```

Your assertion is `assert.equal(edge._key, '595783');`, and it fails because  `undefined == '595783'` is wrong. `edge` is actually a Promise object, which has no `_key` property. Therefore the assertion error.

*(cross-post from [GitHub issue](https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/issues/4112))*